# If $Q$ is a operator on a Hilbert space $U$ and $U_0=Q^{1/2}U$, then $L$ and $LQ^{1/2}$ have the same HS norm, for all operators $L$ from $U_0$ to $H$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $U$ be a $\mathbb R$-Hilbert space, $Q\in\mathfrak L(U)$ be nonnegative and self-adjoint with finite [trace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_class#Definition), $U_0:=Q^{1/2}U$ be equipped with $$\langle u_0,v_0\rangle_{U_0}:=\langle Q^{-1/2}u_0,Q^{-1/2}v_0\rangle_U\;\;\;\text{for }u_0,v_0\in U_0$$ (where $Q^{-1/2}$ denotes the pseudo-inverse, if $Q$ is not injective) and $(\tilde e_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be an orthonormal basis of $(\ker Q^{1/2})^\perp$. It's easy to see that $(Q^{1/2}\tilde e_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is an orthonormal basis of $U_0U$. Moreover, $(\tilde e_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ can be supplemented to a basis of $U$.

> I want to show that $$\left\|L\right\|_{\operatorname{HS}(U_0,\:H)}^2=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\left\|LQ^{1/2}\tilde e_n\right\|_H^2$$ and $$\left\|LQ^{1/2}\right\|_{\operatorname{HS}(U,\:H)}^2=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\left\|LQ^{1/2}e_n\right\|_H^2$$ are equal, for all $L\in\operatorname{HS}(U_0,H)$ (where $\operatorname{HS}(U_0,H)$ denotes the space of [Hilbert-Schmidt operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93Schmidt_operator) from $U_0$ to $H$.

It seems like we need to show that $Q^{1/2}e_k=0$ (i.e. $e_k\in\ker Q^{1/2}$) for all $e_k$ which aren't in $(\tilde e_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$. But I've no idea why this should be the case. I guess we somehow need to use that (since $(\ker Q^{1/2})^\perp$ is closed and $(\ker Q^{1/2})^{\perp\perp}=\overline{\ker Q^{1/2}}=\ker Q^{1/2}$) $$U=(\ker Q^{1/2})^\perp\oplus\ker Q^{1/2}\;,$$ but I don't know how we could do that. Maybe $(e_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ must be constructed by choosing elements from $\ker Q^{1/2}$.

Comment: What do you mean by a pseudo inverse?

Comment: @TrialAndError I mean that $Q^{-1}:=\left(\left.Q\right|_{(\ker Q)^\perp}\right)^{-1}:Q(U)\to(\ker Q)^\perp$.

Comment: Because $Q$ is selfadjoint, then $\mathcal{N}(Q)=\mathcal{N}(Q^{1/2})=\mathcal{R}(Q^{1/2})^{\perp}$.